# Fix Delete Row If String Match in Each sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am setting up  a Diesel Record management system in Excel for a dairy farm. It will function something like a primitive Relational database system. Drivers, vehicles and contractors will each have their own sheet.

I am trying to add a Sub to Delete an Entry if a mistake is made. Each entry has a unique ID in column 1 of the relevant spreadsheets.

My Sub should iterate through all sheets, identify if the ID exist in column 1 of the sheet, and delete the row in which the ID is if it exists in the sheet.

It does not do what I am attempting and I have no idea why. Any help will be massively appreciated.

I have also tried to Select EntireRow instead of Deleting it - just to see if it was selecting the wrong row and deleting, however my code returns RunTime error 1004: “Select method of Range class failed”.

```
'Sub Delete_2()

Dim r As Integer
Dim To_Delete As String

To_Delete = InputBox("Input Entry ID to delete", "Delete Record", 
"Entry_ID")
For Each sht In Worksheets
    For r = sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(r, "A").Value = To_Delete Then
            sht.Rows(r).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next r
Next sht

End Sub'
```

The code runs without error, but does not delete any rows.
I suspect the error has something to do with the ActiveSheet or the Outer For Loop ("For Each sht in WorkSheets"). The macro is activated on a button click. If I put an ID in column 1 of the sheet where the button is, it will delete the correct row. If that same ID is in column 1 of multiple other sheets, the rows will not be deleted. If the Macro is run by button click without the ID in the ActiveSheet, no rows are deleted.

Comment: Try `For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets` and then `If sht.Cells(r, "A").Value = To_Delete Then`

Comment: Hi Damian 
Same result unfortunately

Comment: In which line are you getting error?

Comment: As I said in the description of the problem, the code runs without error but does not delete any rows.

Comment: Is the ID a number on your sheet? In that case declare your variable as Long or Integer.

Comment: The ID number is a String Prefix dependent on the type of Entry, followed by an integer suffix describing the number of entries of that type which have been logged. 

It runs essentially the same as described in this post: [link](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-vba-macros/1202054-help-with-auto-generating-unique-id-in-excel-vba-userform)

Comment: Then this should work... can you pass on a sample of the data so I can try what is wrong?

Comment: Instead of looping through each rows in your sheets and then checking the value of column 1, use filters to filter the sheet in column 1 with your value and then delete the displayed rows. This approach should result in performance enhancements as well

Comment: @Damian I'm happy to pass along my whole spreadsheet?

Comment: Try the answer below and if it doesn't work, pass it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your code little bit by making the references fully qualified.

It works at my end. See if it works for you.

```
Dim r As Integer
Dim To_Delete As String
To_Delete = InputBox("Input Entry ID to delete", "Delete Record", "Entry_ID")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For r = sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        If sht.Cells(r, "A").Value = To_Delete Then
            sht.Cells(r, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next r
Next sht
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```